# The labels are not same as figure in lineplot in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

```
comp_fib1=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,3,6,7,7,11,18,30,47,88,143]
comp_fib2=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(
    data=[comp_fib1,comp_fib2],legend=False,markers=['*','o'],palette='colorblind')
plt.legend(title='Fibonacci series',loc='upper left',labels={'fib1','fib2'})
plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
```

[This is the image of the figure formed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h8sD.jpg)

I used the above code, I customized the handles but they are not the same as the figure.
Is there any way that i can get the right handle with customized name?

Comment: change to `ax=sns.lineplot(
    data=[comp_fib1,comp_fib2],legend='full',markers=['*','o'],palette='colorblind')`  and then add `handles, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` , then `ax.legend(handles=handles,title='Fibonacci series',loc='upper left',labels={'fib1','fib2'})`

Comment: To change the title and the legend location of Seaborn legends, `ax.move_legend(...)` is usually the easiest. To change the labels, changing the input data is recommended.  E.g. `ax = sns.lineplot(data={'fib1': comp_fib1, 'fib2': comp_fib2}, legend=True, markers=['*', 'o'], palette='colorblind')` and `ax.move_legend(title='Fibonacci series', loc='upper left')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027304/seaborn-scatterplot-legend-breaks-when-editing-with-plt-legend) is a relevant question.

As a simple workaround, I found that using Pandas helps alleviate the need to edit the legend labels via `plt` (which breaks the final rendering). You just have to create a DataFrame with two columns, the names of which are the labels you want to show inside the legend. Seaborn will use these column names as legend labels by default.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'fib1': comp_fib1, 'fib2': comp_fib2})
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, legend='full', markers=['*', 'o'], palette='colorblind')
ax.legend(title='Fibonacci series', loc='upper left')
```

[image]